# Unable to terminate simultaneously running scripts at once in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I am trying to run 2 files, namely a python script called **PaperCapture.py**, and a bash script **PrinterAutomation.sh** simultaneously, since my task requires them to start at the same time. The python script is used to click pictures using a camera, and the bash script is used to send an echo signal to a printer, in order to print something and feed forward the paper.

I wrote another bash script called **ScriptStart.sh** which can start both these scripts simultaneously, but when I press **Ctrl + C**, or even try to kill the processes, the PrinterAutomation.sh script keeps running in the background, even when the terminal has been closed.

The code of ScriptStart.sh is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

#=============================================================================
# INITIAL SCRIPT FOR STARTING CAMERA & PRINTER SCRIPTS
#=============================================================================

python3 PaperCapture.py &  PIDIOS=$!
sudo sh ./PrinterAutomation.sh &  PIDMIX=$!
wait $PIDIOS

PID=pidof ./PrinterAutomation.sh
echo $PID
kill -INT $PID
```

If anyone can help me to figure this out, it would be great. All I need is for both the scripts to start simultaneously, and for PrinterAutomation.sh to stop running when PaperCapture.py has stopped running.

## =======================================

**UPDATE:**

Removing pidof and using sudo kill -INT "$PIDMIX" terminates the scripts in the terminal foreground, but PrinterAutomation.sh still keeps running in the background.

This was fixed by adding the line

```
trap "kill 0" EXIT
```

at the top

Comment: You save `PIDMIX` but then ignore it; why? `pidof` is somewhat more likely to return the wrong PID.

Comment: I tried to use it instead of PID, but it gave the same result. So I assumed that pidof might give a different result, because this code worked one time

Comment: Concerning your question, two notes: Firstly, Bash is nothing Linux-specific. Secondly, process management in Bash is independent of the code the process is running, so here's nothing Python-specific either. If you had extracted a [mcve], you would have found at least the latter. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to kill a process which isn't yours. Try

```
sudo kill -INT "$PIDMIX"
```

and probably get rid of the pointless and somewhat error-prone extra call to `pidof` (which also has a syntax error anyway; you probably meant

```
PID=$(pidof ./PrinterAutomation.sh)
```

or even better, [prefer lower case for your private variables.)](/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)